# how to send multiple image object to client in node express?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am new in angular. I have a set of images & I want to display it on to the client browser on a load of the page.

Is it possible or not?

I am able to send a single file but not multiple files now I am stuck can someone help me.

Thanks for help

```
router.get('/getList', function(req, res, next) {
  var fileNames = [];

  fileNames = readDir.readSync('/NodeWorkspace/uploads/output/', ['**.png']);

  var data = {};

  fileNames.forEach(function(filename) {
    filepath = path.join(__dirname, '../../uploads/output') + '/' + filename;

    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../uploads/output') + '/' + filename, function(err, content) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(content);
      }
    });
  });

  //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../../uploads/output/', fileNames[0]));

  response.data = fileNames;
  res.json(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert fs callback to promise and read all parallel once done send response.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const db = require('../db');
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

router.get('/getList', function (req, res, next) {
    var fileNames = [];

    fileNames = readDir.readSync('/NodeWorkspace/uploads/output/', ['**.png']);  // use async function instead of sync
    var data = {};
    const files = fileNames.map(function (filename) {
        filepath = path.join(__dirname, '../../uploads/output') + '/' + filename;
       return readFile(filepath); //updated here
    });

    Promise.all(files).then(fileNames => {
        response.data = fileNames;
        res.json(response);
    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(400).json(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: it gives null response to me. "data":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]}

Comment: @Pramod I missed the return, I have updated my answer plz check.

Comment: thanks, it gives the response can you suggest me how to display that object into a browser.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: actually, I am trying to display multiple images on the client browser in a single request. I did for the single image but for multiple images, I can't. is there any other way to achieve this I want to display multiple images with some image processing operation on it in the client side.

Comment: @Pramod have you found an answer? I also want to display multiple images on the client browser in a single request. How do you do it for multiple images?